# Getting CMake to use -L instead of -I

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++

I'm trying to build a project that requires the use of -L in a g++ command (`g++ x.cpp -ldfp -L /usr/include/dfp`) due to the use of `#include_next` in the library. When using `target_include_directories(target BEFORE PRIVATE /usr/include/dfp)` then it generates a compile command with -I (`/usr/bin/c++ -I/usr/include/dfp -g -fPIC -std=c++17 -o CMakeFiles/x.dir/x.cpp.o -c /home/<user>/project/x/x.cpp`). This then results in compiler errors about missing declarations.

If the compiler command is then run with `-L` (by manually copying it from compile_commands.json) then the object can be built correctly. Is there a way to get CMake to export the required `-L` command?

Comment: `-L` has nothing to do whatsoever with include directories or `#include_next`. `-L /usr/include/dfp` will just do absolutely nothing to your include files, so you need to simply remove `/usr/include/dfp` from `target_include_directories`.